# Google Sheets snapshot of a range to another sheet when value of cell equals a certain value

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, snapshot

I have a sheet in which users can input values in a range AB2:AV21. In cells AB24 to AV24 there is a formula which indicates when a deadline is met. It consists of 21 different deadlines and as such 21 ranges. The reason I use formula deadlines is that each user gets their copy of this sheet and it makes it easier to change the deadlines from one single access point.

I want to copy and paste each subsequent range when their respective deadline is met to another sheet. I.e. Copy AB2:AB21 when AB24 equals "Deadline met" from sheet 'Selectie' to sheet 'Copy Selectie'. A snapshot from the exact moment the value in the deadline cell changes to "Deadline met".

OnEdit probably won't work here as it need to be triggered by a formula. So I guess the first step is to make an importrange to another sheet so the script can use OnChange. However if users paste values into the original range I don't want these to be copied over the previous snapshot when the deadline was met.

Hope someone's wants to help me out.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

#### Copy on "Deadline met" every hour

```
function lookfordeadline() {
  const ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
  const sh = ss.getSheetByName("Selectie");
  const csh = ss.getSheetByName("Copy Selectie");
  const vs = sh.getRange("AB24:AV24").getValues().flat();
  vs.forEach((c, i) => {
    if (c == "Deadline met") {
      csh.appendRow(sh.getRange(2, i + 24, 20).getValues().flat())
    }
  });
}
```

Need to run this once to create the trigger.

```
function createTBTrigger() {
  if(ScriptApp.getProjectTriggers().filter(t => t.getHandlerFunction() == "lookfordeadline").length == 0) {
    ScriptApp.newTrigger("lookfordeadline").timeBased().everyHours(1).create();
  }
}
```

Comment: Thanks but the code doesn't seem to work unfortunately. When debugging I get  
TypeError: sh.getRange(...).getValue(...).flat is not a function. When changing getValue to getValues it completes the function but does not work quite right. (changed small typo in "lookfordealine" too) Looks like it transposes the data instead of copying the vertical range and pasting it vertical.

Here is a sample sheet which makes things a bit more clear I think.
https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1QEi4PodKeBfHU_VCf8KEWjSj5hRhanI05nm4Mqkxuk4/edit?usp=sharing

Comment: I had a mispelling in the trigger function name

Comment: Yes I noticed and fixed it, but the copy function didn't work.

Comment: I found another typo.

Comment: Yes noticed that also as explained in my message earlier. It however transposes data horizontally instead of copy paste it vertically. A sample sheet is in my message before.